# The type or namespace name 'Bind' and 'Include' in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating a `.Net` Application to `.Net Core`. In `.Net` Application, we were using `bind` and `include` keyword on the top of a model class for the LoginInfo as below:

```
[Bind(Include = "UserName,Password")]
```

But after conversion, it is showing this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Bind' and 'Include' could not be found.

[image]

Can you suggest what can be added in place of those keywords in .Net core MVC.

Comment: You are missing a line at the top saying `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`

Comment: Visual Studio should be giving you the option to add that automatically if you click on the line and see the little icon that appears

Comment: I was not showing me the option to add it automatically. So, I manually added it. But still showing same error.

Comment: Note the `Mvc` has a red wiggly underline too; "are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: Is this in a class library outside of your ASP.NET web project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bind attribute exists in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace meaning that you need to import it like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

If that isn't working, likely because this class exists in a class library outside of your ASP.NET Core web project, then you need to add a framework reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. To do this, edit your csproj file and add this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) for more details.

Finally, you don't need to name the `Include` parameter, so it should simply look like this:

```
[Bind("UserName,Password")]
public class LoginInfo
{
    //snip...
```